# How to replace image formdata with Javascript after compressing the data?

Tags: javascript, form-data, image-compression, data-uri

There are various image compression libraries, that can simply read the file attached to a form's `<input>`, but I'm lacking the skill to 'return' the new compressed image back to *that* `<input>`, so it's attached to the form/application and can be processed.

Whatever library I try, and often in the console can see the old/new size values, and press 'submit' on the form to send the image to the server, always the original image is sent over, not the new compressed one.

How would I replace the image that the user selects for the `<input type="file">` with the new DataURL that is created with Javascript? I think I just need a line of code or two to replace the value/data, but which?

<sub>Providing code is a little difficult, because I haven't set on a specific compression library. Let's just assume we've got a form with an `<input>`, an OnChange Event handler and a function that reads the data and returns a new DataUrl.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As far I remember due to security reasons browsers won't allow you to modify the `FileList`.

Anyway, you can solve your task by appending a hidden field to your form and setting the data URI as Base64 value for the hidden field. On form submit clear the original file field (if you do not need it) while on the server side you have to decode Base64 value of the hidden field.

If ajax requests are ok for you, another option is to use `FormData` and `XMLHttpRequest` (for some good examples check [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)).